# java.io.IOException: Stream closed when unmarshaling with JAXBContext

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, ioexception

I wrote an unmarshal method which is accessed by a bunch of tests running in parallel to read data from XML files.

This method sits in a maven commons dependency module added to my main module.
I am facing java.io.IOException: Stream closed exception in a very inconsistent fashion and cannot reproduce it locally. It only happens when my tests run in CI in Jenkins and that too not very often. Code is below.

```
public <T> Object internalUnmarshal(String url, Class<T> clazz)
        throws JAXBException,DataException, ClassNotFoundException,IOException 
{

    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);

    try {
        if (is == null) {
            throw new DataException("''{0}'' not found.", url);
        }
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(Class.forName(clazz.getCanonicalName());
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        return unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
         throw new JAXBException(e);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }

}
```

I even added a synchronized block as below but same issue was reproduced in jenkins server run.

```
synchronized(this){
            return unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
        }
```

Stack trace below :-

```
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:

    [java.io.IOException: Stream closed]]
        at com.paydiant.commons.data.unmarshalers.XMLUnmarshaler.internalUnmarshal(XMLUnmarshaler.java:116)
        at com.paydiant.commons.data.unmarshalers.XMLUnmarshaler.resloveToUnmarshaledObjectList(XMLUnmarshaler.java:76)
        at com.paydiant.commons.data.unmarshalers.XMLUnmarshaler.doUnmarshalObjects(XMLUnmarshaler.java:36)
        ... 67 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
     - with linked exception:
    [java.io.IOException: Stream closed]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:261)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:229)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:204)
        at com.paydiant.commons.data.unmarshalers.XMLUnmarshaler.internalUnmarshal(XMLUnmarshaler.java:112)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:258)
        ... 73 more
```

Any ideas what might be causing this ?

Comment: this was fixed by invoking another constructor for Unmarshaller  as  unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(contents)); where contents is a String.